# Cannot add Redmine plugin - LoadError: cannot load such file -- redmine/wiki_formatting/textile/redcloth3

Tags: ruby, rake, rvm, redmine

Added Redmine plugin to:

```
/usr/share/redmine/plugins/redmine_wiki_extensions
```

Changed directory to:

```
/usr/share/redmine/
```

Executed:

```
rake redmine:plugins:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
```

And I get:

```
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- redmine/wiki_formatting/textile/redcloth3
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plugin migration worked well with previous version:

```
redmine_wiki_extensions-0.7.0.zip
```

Instead of:

```
redmine_wiki_extensions-0.8.0.zip
```

Environment:

```
  Redmine version                3.3.0.stable
  Ruby version                   2.2.7-p470 
  Rails version                  4.2.6
```